# If one thread throwing an exception then How to stop other waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

In Java If I have three thread **t1,t2** and **t3**. Suppose **t1** is executing some task and **t2,t3** are in a waiting state. Now If **t1** is facing/throwing any kind of exception then I do not want to execute my **t2,t3** thread.

*How can we achive this functionality in Java?*

Comment: Don't use Threads, use the executor framework.

Comment: @AndyTurner. On the one hand that's good advice. On the other, it's nice to learn how the internals work through lower level objects. This would be a good question if OP put a little work into doing his own research.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use threads directly, use the executor framework.

Specifically, use a `CompletionService`, so that you can retrieve the tasks you submit to the executor in order of completion (successful or otherwise).

Instead of:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> { /* runnable 1 */ });
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> { /* runnable 2 */ });
Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> { /* runnable 3 */ });
```

Create a `CompletionService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = ...;  // e.g. Executors.newFixedThreadPool
CompletionService completionService = new CompletionService(executor);
```

Now, create a list to hold the `Future`s returned by submitting tasks to the `CompletionService`:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
futures.add(completionService.submit(() -> { /* runnable 1 */ })); 
futures.add(completionService.submit(() -> { /* runnable 2 */ })); 
futures.add(completionService.submit(() -> { /* runnable 3 */ }));
```

Now, use `take` to get the futures in order of completion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i) {
  Future<?> completed = futures.take();
  try {
    completed.get();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // An exception occurred whilst running the task.
    // Cancel all the tasks.
    futures.forEach(f -> f.cancel(true));
  }
}
```

Of course, for the `cancel` to do anything useful here, you would need your runnables to check for interruption; but you'd need to have some means of checking for "failure" in your other threads anyway.

Comment: I think instead of iterating over the `futures` list, you should be `poll()`ing the `completionService`.  Not really sure though, and didn't test it.